# Angular: template from inner html and add existing data

Tags: angularjs

Trying to add li from template and add items from `$scope.menuItems` (controller) 
Items don't display
http://plnkr.co/edit/Jo7Vml?p=preview

```
app.directive("menuDemo", function(){
   return {
      templateUrl: 'tree-renderer.html'
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go : http://plnkr.co/edit/8YV6cdCIPCjEOq3DtjAz?p=preview

First : added the following to the directive :

```
 scope:{
          menuItems:"=menuDemo"
  },
```

This enable the two-way binding on the data you pass to the `menu-demo` attribute when using your directives, without this you can't pass data to your directive.

Second : remove the `script` tag in the tree-renderer.html and sub-tree-renderer.html. Script tag is only usefull when using `ng-include` along with it. You were just define a template part without using it like this.

Third adding a top level ng-repeat for the 1st level in tree-renderer.html and remove the one from index.html.

```
<div ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">
```

As you can see `menuItems` match with what i have defined in the `scope:{}` part.

Fourth : I added the binding of the function `addItem` and `addSubItem` so you can define your own way of adding items to the tree outisde of the directive.

EDIT : Another plnkr where i move out the `<div ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">` http://plnkr.co/edit/MZ3nsY6WTG3EiNKhXjAv?p=preview.

As you can see i put the menu-demo call in a `<span>` tag within the `<li>` tag. This is because they both use isoled scope and if i want to use data from the ng-repeat loop the easiest way is to move the other directive in a child DOM element.

Note that i also change the name of the binding element to menuItem (i remove the 's').

Comment: Sorry, but first div tag in 'tree-renderer.html' is unnecessary for me. How can I transfer 'ng-repeat' from that div ?

Comment: This doens't work: <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" class="menu" menu-demo="menuItems" menu-add-item="addItem" menu-add-sub-item="addSubItem"></li>

Comment: It's better but do you have any other ideas? That span breaks css :(

Comment: i would need the said css for this or that you point me what is not working, i don't have anything that seems to break in my fiddle.

Comment: css-file is huge so i will confuse adding needed css selectors to plnkr. if it possible not to break html structure it will be great

Comment: i just retested without the span and it work now... strange here is the line : `<li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" class="menu" menu-demo="menuItem" menu-add-item="addItem" menu-add-sub-item="addSubItem"></li>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my higher comment I use menu-demo="menuItems" but needed menu-demo="menuItem"

Answer (score 0):

That is not a correct way to declare a directive try something like this:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('menu', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: 'tree-renderer.html',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                //here some functions that do something
            }
        };
}]);
```

By the way, try improve your questions!